# Get the ID of an elements who have dynamic ID values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a newbie in Jquery. I have a table in my webpage which shows the contents of a user table from the database.I have also created an edit button and Delete button for each row of data.I need the id of each edit and delete button for writing code for editing and deleting the records in the database as well as implementing this changes in the table in the webpage also.

```
   $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_details");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['mname']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['childname']."</td>";
          echo "<td><input type='button' id = 'edit".$row['Id']."' value='Edit'></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='button' id = 'delete".$row['Id']."' value='Delete'></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
      }
```

If I am using Jquery,how to get the `ID`of each button?Or If I write a onclick event using javascript for each button and passes the ID's as arguments,can I access via Jquery.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add common class name and use that as a selector to get id of the buttons like below

Try like this

```
$(document).on('click','.edit_btn',function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
$(document).on('click','.del_btn',function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

HTML

```
<input type='button' id ='edit' class="edit_btn" value='Edit'>
<input type='button' id ='delete' class="del_btn" value='Delete'>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDz59/29/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button").each(function(index, item) {
    var itemId = $(item).attr('id');
});
```

But I would set the $row['id'] into a data-id attribute and then use:

```
$("button").each(function(index, item) {
    var itemId = $(item).data('id');
});
```

Comment: You can simplify the body of the `each` callback to `var itemId = this.id;` (in the first case).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and Event Delegation

```
$(document).on("click" , "[id^='edit']" ,function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});

$(document).on("click" , "[id^='delete']" , function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: @down voters can explain what is the issue i made in the above code?

Comment: @sudharsan Please register this events with the use of event delegation, since the OP's html elements are loaded dynamically.. I guess that should be the reason for the down votes... :)

Comment: Anyone, Can u Please explain what did i mistake in the above code?

Comment: can I write in this way? it is posiible

Comment: @SridharR This should work.. please see the console. How can you say that this wont work..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i did not say it wont work,i just said to him check with this fiddle because @Tamizh he asking can I write in this way? thats why..anyway thanks `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `data-*` attribute to specify the ID and use a common class to call the click handler

```
echo "<td><input type='button' id = 'edit".$row['Id']."' data-id='".$row['Id']."' value='Edit' class='edit-record'></td>";
```

then in jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.edit-record', function () {
        //this is called when the edit button is clicked
        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.data('id');
        //now id has the value of current record's id
    })
})
```

Comment: @SridharR int that case use event delegation

Comment: @SridharR but I don't think OP is having dynamic elements as the elements are created in html - unless that html is not loaded as a fragment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to escape your variables in HTML context using `htmlspecialchars()`. Second, you can use data attributes to easily identify the record that needs be edited or deleted.

```
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['mname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['childname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="edit" data-id="<?= $row['Id'] ?>" value="Edit"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="delete" data-id="<?= $row['Id'] ?>" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<?php
```

Then, you can use classes to identify the buttons instead:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // edit stuff
});

$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // delete stuff
});
```